# SSRS Expression for =PRODUCT(1+D5:D17)-1 in excel

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report, where, I want the trailing 1, 3, 5 year calculation. Similar calculation is happening in excel for 1 year with this "`=PRODUCT(1+D5:D17)-1`". I have tried Running Row with sum and aggregate function but no success.
I do have Date and value(`%`) parameter from july 2010 to current date. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Sample Sheet :
The formula is applied on the Net Stream.

```
Gross   Net     Fees        Trailing 1 Year     Trailing 3 Year     Trailing 5 Year     Trailing 10 Year
Oct-10  1.54%   1.34%       0.19%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Nov-10  0.90%   0.78%       0.12%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Dec-10  2.28%   1.93%       0.34%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A                 N/A

Jan-11  -0.75%  -0.86%      0.11%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Feb-11  0.65%   0.56%       0.09%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Mar-11  0.07%   -0.02%      0.09%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Apr-11  0.93%   0.82%       0.10%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A                 N/A
May-11  -0.88%  -0.96%      0.09%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Jun-11  -1.30%  -1.38%      0.07%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Jul-11  0.27%   0.18%       0.09%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Aug-11  -3.95%  -4.04%      0.09%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Sep-11  -5.68%  -5.77%      0.09%               -7.43%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Oct-11  4.89%   4.82%       0.07%               -4.26%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Nov-11  -1.09%  -1.18%      0.09%               -6.12%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Dec-11  -1.26%  -1.30%      0.03%               -9.10%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A

Jan-12  2.73%   2.63%       0.11%               -5.90%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Feb-12  2.19%   2.10%       0.09%               -4.46%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Mar-12  0.79%   0.71%       0.08%               -3.76%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Apr-12  -0.79%  -0.87%      0.08%               -5.38%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A
May-12  -3.82%  -3.89%      0.07%               -8.17%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Jun-12  0.67%   0.59%       0.08%               -6.34%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Jul-12  0.75%   0.67%       0.08%               -5.88%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Aug-12  1.45%   1.37%       0.08%               -0.58%              N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Sep-12  1.78%   1.70%       0.08%               7.30%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Oct-12  1.24%   1.18%       0.06%               3.58%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Nov-12  0.27%   0.20%       0.07%               5.03%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A
Dec-12  0.98%   0.91%       0.07%               7.38%               N/A                 N/A                 N/A
```

[image]

Comment: Please, add sample of data, and what result you need and have you tried.

Comment: Hi. thanks for the suggestion, Have added the snip sample.

Comment: It is better to post actual data - not screenshot. Please, do it for 2010-2011 years. And how do you count `Trailing Year 1` f.e. for September 2011?

Comment: I screwed it up, but this is the data.

Comment: Fixed! How do you get `-4.26% ` for `Oct-11`?

Comment: that is trailing 3 year. i have copied the data from inbetween . wait ill post data from start to mid.

Comment: sorry, the data is correct just got misplaced with fees.

Comment: So.. how to count it? F.e. I take data for Oct-10, Oct-09, Oct-08 and sum it? Or get average? How?

Comment: well excel use product of net stream. in ssrs there is no product function but I am looking for Log function for help.

Comment: Ok, another try :) *The Excel PRODUCT function returns the product (multiplication) of a supplied set of numerical values.* so you are using `=PRODUCT(1+D5:D17)-1` what is for `Oct-11` in that formula?

Comment: Its a compounding way ((1+first net value) *(1+Second Net val)...-1) for year